# Postfix: Setup corret certificate chain

Tags: ssl, certificate, postfix-mta

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
I can't get TLS to work properly on my Postfix-server.

I have a wildcard certificate from Thawte and I have put the wildcard and intermediate certificate in the same file. This is my main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.165.199.0/24
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
biff = no

smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/cert/device.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/cert/device.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cert/rootCA.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

and this is my certificate file (I didn't paste the entire certificate).

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGsDCCBZigAwIBAgIQSgo15k4YWfFlAngSiZuLETANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBD
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMdGhhd3RlLCBJbmMuMR0wGwYDVQQDExR0
...........Wildcard certificate............
gjgbXl6MjrVSj6FfDNJFjemtNRyHVEG+pOIE3s2bdxbW0GyKUu4Xv1lhs81AbriG
cCtxINchiAgsWURmK1oq8ebScFpgv30UWEpdkyToAjSbl1wq
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3DCCA8SgAwIBAgIQPiM0Wu0sClF7Jt7UgB0QqjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
rjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
......Intermediate certificate........
Hi36v6dJog2X9ZbC6WzUzUcLi4oBi9v6z5J1Lt4+p3O1/gNRp0LDx0JrqW++9iDh
jr+fCY7lCOiSk3c+SUScf+l5nf9Lr+A4VzQNXxEyEpKpYYiBpR74oPBFWoZxIIWF
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When I run `openssl s_client -connect smtp-out.domain.com:587 -starttls smtp`

I get messages like these:

> unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> unable to verify the first certificate
>
> certificate not trusted

```
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=SE/ST=State/L=City/O=Company/OU=INC/CN=*.domain.com
   i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./CN=thawte SHA256 SSL CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=thawte DV SSL SHA256 CA
   i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2008 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3
```

What do I have to do to get this working properly?
Obviously I'm missing something but I can't figure out what.

Also I get this in the log:

```
warning: TLS library problem: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1315:SSL alert number 48:
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question but I just found [this](https://whatsmychaincert.com) wonderful site

I generated a correct chain with root certificate and used that instead and not it works.